# subtract current_time from timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, timestamp

I have a table where each entry has a timestamp. I am using this timestamp to calculate e.g. the number of entries per day in the last week. However, I do not really care whether the results that I get represent a particular day. The actual goal is to divide the entries into 24h-bins that I can compare and see whether there has been any significant change over time. Furthermore, since I am working with almost real-time data, I would like to perform this analysis at any time and also take into account the most recent entries. If I would just group the entries per day and perform the query in the middle of the day then I would get a not particularly insightful result for the current day.

My idea was now to subtract the current time from the timestamp of the entries and then do the grouping by days. This way I could get 24h-bins each of which represents a full 24h period and the  youngest one also contains the most recent entries.

Something like this:
`created_on - current_time`

Of course I cannot subtract a time from a timestamp. Is there a way to convert current_time into an interval? Or is there an entirely different approach that is easier?

Comment: `extract(days FROM current_timestamp - created_on)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert current_time into an interval?

Yes, just cast it.

Note that the use of `current_time` [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_CURRENT_TIME) so it's better to use `localtime` instead.

You can do:

```
created_on - localtime::interval
```

But it seems you might just want to set the time part of the timestamp to `00:00:00` which you can do by using `date_trunc()`

```
date_trunc('day', created_on)
```

Comment: yes, that works as well! thank you! I did not know about the discouraged use of `current_time` but now it is also a bit more clear why casting `current_time` as an interval didn't work.
However, the last part with `date_trunc` does not really what I wanted because then I still end up with less than 24 hours worth of entries (assuming a more or less constant influx of entries) in the most recent bin/date/day.